# Adjusting a view's vertical alignment relative to a sibling view

Tags: android, android-layout

I have been experimenting with linear and relative layouts to achieve the result in the link below.  Ideally, I want to place view B to the right of view A (which is no problem whatsoever) and have the bottom of view B be along a horizontal line roughly 3/4 the height of view A.  Is there a way for me to assign the bottom position of view B relative to the height on view A without referencing the parent container?  Perhaps setting the bottom of view B to some dy from view A's horizontal centerline?

All attempts with margins and padding (positive and negative), gravity, and aligning to the parent's various walls have proved fruitless.  I usually end up bringing in excess height to the parent view or cutting off part of view B.

[image]

Comment: Some code would help us

Answer (score 0):

You can, but it will be a bit odd.  Use a RelativeLayout, and place View A in it.  Place a LinearLayout to its right with its bottom aligned to the bottom of View A and top to the top of View A.  In that linear layout, place View B and an empty view.  Weigh View A and View B within that linear layout so they are 3:1.  That should give you the effect you want.

Answer (score 0):

You should use coordinatorLayout for this.
[Coordinator UI](https://saulmm.github.io/mastering-coordinator)